# jquery mobile conflict with a function when a new page is retrieved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a form for users to login to the site and  have placed it in the main menu with opacity set to zero.
when a user clicks on login he would be supposed to see the form with performing the function below:

```
$("#login-form-show").click(function(){
    $("form.hidden").animate({opacity:1},400);
});
```

and the form itself has a button which will call a function to hide the form  again as below:

```
$("#form-close-button").click(function(){
    $("form.hidden").animate({opacity:0},400);
});
```

it works in the first page and all the pages if they start to load by the user, but the problem is that when the jqueryMobile retrieves the page with its default "pagination" or "method of page loading" which uses ajax, the above functions wouldn't work. (the user has to reload the page to access the form).
Note that I have called the script in all pages and on my logic, it  should work.

Also note that I am using php, purecss, jquery, jqueryMobile.

you can see the problem in this url:
www.obpchap.com

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error on your page. But when I insert any credentials and click "Log in", I get the error "Error Loading Page"

Comment: because it doesn't work yet and it's not important. i meant that the displaying process of the form is my problem. when you click on login and if you transfer to a page and again click on login on the menue.(the default menu button)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that after changing the page, the element with the id "login-form-show" exists twice in the DOM:
[image]

I do not know, how you can replace the old page with the new page using jQuery mobile. But you should aim for that.

Comment: I didn't see that copy of my site and don't know why it copies it in the document, but as you said I thought that the problem will be solved with using classes to reach the login button and the close button. so I tried that and wow. it solved; Thank you bro.

Comment: Glad you could solve the problem! Would you mind to accept or upvote my answer?

Comment: I tried but unfortunately I'm nut popular enough to vote. I will when I reached that fame.